# Docker Setup for centos 7

Tags: .net, docker, .net-core, firewalld

Hello I am new to docker and am trying to setup docker on a centos 7 environment.
I have installed docker using https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/centos/ and then tried to get a site running using this https://docs.docker.com/engine/examples/dotnetcore/#build-and-run-the-docker-image. I have tried to do wget on locahost and the docker ip on those ports to no avail.

This is what i have executed:

```
docker build -t aspnetapp .

docker run -it -d --name myapp aspnetapp
```

this is the docker file

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-aspnetcore-runtime AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 64928
EXPOSE 44340

FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-sdk AS build

COPY .  /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN dotnet restore "TestDocker.csproj"

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "TestDocker.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM base AS final

COPY --from=publish /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "TestDocker.dll"]
```

This builds and runs perfectly

```
[root@local testSite]# docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                  NAMES
b6044951aa7d        aspnetapp           "dotnet TestDocker.d…"   45 minutes ago      Up 45 minutes       44340/tcp, 64928/tcp   myapp
```

Firewall D:

```
[root@local testdocker]# firewall-cmd --list-all
public (active)
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces: enp9s0
  sources:
  services: ssh dhcpv6-client http https
  ports: 44340/tcp 64928/tcp  443/tcp 80/tcp
  protocols:
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports:
  source-ports:
  icmp-blocks:
  rich rules:
```

I thought I would be able to access it straight from the browser but I have had no luck. Even if there are instructions for this somewhere could someone point me in that direction.

Could this be the issue

```
Dec 12 14:40:58 local.office firewalld[2591]: WARNING: COMMAND_FAILED: '/usr/sbin/iptables -w2 -t nat -C POSTROUTING -p tcp -s 172.17.0.2 -d 172.17.0.2 --dport 64928 -j MASQUERADE' failed: iptables: No chain/target/match by that name.
Dec 12 14:40:58 local.office firewalld[2591]: WARNING: COMMAND_FAILED: '/usr/sbin/iptables -w2 -t nat -C DOCKER -p tcp -d 0/0 --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.17.0.2:64928 ! -i docker0' failed: iptables: No chain/target/match by that name.
Dec 12 14:42:36 local.office firewalld[2591]: WARNING: COMMAND_FAILED: '/usr/sbin/iptables -w2 -t filter -C DOCKER ! -i docker0 -o docker0 -p tcp -d 172.17.0.2 --dport 64928 -j ACCEPT' failed: iptables: Bad rule (does a matching rule exist in that chain?).
Dec 12 14:42:36 local.office firewalld[2591]: WARNING: COMMAND_FAILED: '/usr/sbin/iptables -w2 -t nat -C POSTROUTING -p tcp -s 172.17.0.2 -d 172.17.0.2 --dport 64928 -j MASQUERADE' failed: iptables: No chain/target/match by that name.
Dec 12 14:43:18 local.office firewalld[2591]: WARNING: COMMAND_FAILED: '/usr/sbin/iptables -w2 -t nat -C DOCKER -p tcp -d 0/0 --dport 64928 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.17.0.2:64928 ! -i docker0' failed: iptables: No chain/target/match by that name.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although FirewallD is the default firewall programme for CentOS 7, it is deactivated by default on a new CentOS 7 server. Therefore, let's activate it and add the required network ports.
You may try to add the ports in your firewall application using below.

```
firewall-cmd --add-port=64928/tcp --permanent

firewall-cmd --add-port=44340/tcp --permanent
```

OR

You can check with your Docker firewall rules once as those are the rules set before the default firewall management tools on the OS.

```
iptables -L -v -n -t nat --line-numbers
```

You can check those using above command.

Answer (score 1):

Docker containers have their own networking stack. You need to expose the ports on your container to the outside world and also map those ports to the host ports. You can do this with the "-p" flag.

For details, kindly refer:

https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/

Comment: Can I add http and https so like -p 80:44340 -p 443:64928

Comment: I added the ports and still I am unable to connect